# How to create the following image as header background in HTML5 and CSS3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a site.Is it possible to make a div with a curved bottom by using html5 css3 and javascript. It's look like

[Curved header bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIzUR.png)

Comment: Show some code which you have tried and post specific issue which you are facing

Comment: yes, its possible.

Comment: you can check the examples http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp

Comment: Share your code pls!

Comment: Your code should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
 }

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  top: -200px;
  left: -50%;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200%;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='inner'>
  </div>
 </div>
```